# How to inject spring beans into spock test

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spock

I am new to spock. I am trying to write a spock unit test against a standalone java app that uses JDK 1.7, Spring 3.1, Groovy 1.8.6, Spock 0.6, Maven 3.0.4. A basic hello world spock test is working. However when I try to test spring beans, I find that they are not getting injected. I use the approach mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpringExtension). businessObjectDao is null within *when* block. How do I get this working?

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:test-appContext.xml")
class BusinessObjectPersistenceTest extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    BusinessObjectDao businessObjectDao

    def "business never set at least once"() {
        when:
            BusinessObjectDao.getBusinessObject()
        then:
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `getBusinessObject` method actually _static_ (Capital `B` on `BusinessObjectDao` reference)?  If so, then I don't think you'd need to inject an _instance_ of it in the first place?

Comment: Probably a more recent Spring/Spock reference (for injection):  https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/module_spring.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you most likely forgot to include a Spock Spring dependency.

Here is how to get it using:

### maven

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
   <version>0.6-groovy-1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

### gradle

```
'org.spockframework:spock-spring:0.6-groovy-1.8'
```

### plain groovy

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.spockframework', module='spock-spring', version='0.6-groovy-1.8')
)
```

---

**`0.6-groovy-1.8` is the current version, if you need another one, just substitute*

Comment: The current version is 0.6-groovy-1.8.

Comment: yes, and it is [20 days old](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/spockframework/spock-spring/0.6-groovy-1.8/). noted and corrected.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but let me just add one comment for `arrehman`.
If this is a unit test and not an integration test what you are doing, You should be mocking that DAO. In any case +1 for the answer.

Comment: @sfrj i think there is some disagreement in the testing world about your statement. it goes to mockists vs statists. some would say you should only mock adapters and ports. a dao is likely is neither.

Comment: The **current** version can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-spring)

Answer (score 0):

For others arriving here that don't have their test class annotated as a Bean (the example in this Question *does* have sufficient annotation for that), that would of course be at least a necessary prior step for injection (in general).