# How to set objects while functional testing grails with Spock

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I've got a sample Domain such as this

```
class User {
    String username
    String password

    def userHelper

    static contraints = {
        username(nullable: false, blank: false)
        password nullable: false, blank: false, validator: {pwd, userInstance ->
            return userInstance.userHelper.validatePassword(pwd)
        }
    }
}
```

the `userHelper` is being injected by the following in my `resources.groovy`

```
beans = {
    userHelper(UserHelper)
}
```

When I test my application from the browser, everything runs fine. However, I get an exception while trying to write functional tests for this.

The error says: `Cannot invoke method validatePassword() on null object`

So I'm assuming that `userHelper` is not being set when I run my functional test case.

My test case looks like this:

```
 @TestFor(UserController)
 @Mock([User])

class UserControllerSpecification extends Specification {


    def "save user" () {
        given:
            request.contentType = "application/json"
            request.JSON = """
                            {user:
                                {
                                    username: "somtething"
                                    password: "something"
                                }
                            }
                        """
        when: 
            controller.save()

        then:
            User.count() == 1
    }
}
```

**Update**

Controller:

```
class UserController {
    def userService
    def save() {
        def user = new User(params?.user)
        request.withFormat {
            json {
                if(user.validate())
                  userService.processUser()
                  //do something
                else
                  //do something else
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions**

- How can I set the `userHelper` property on `User` domain prior to running my tests?
- How can I run my code in `Bootstrap.groovy` prior to running all my functional and integration test cases?

Comment: Did you mean `return userInstance.userHelper.validatePassword(pwd)`, or `return userHelper.validatePassword(pwd)`?

Comment: I meant `return userInstance.userHelper.validatePassword(pwd)` as I understand, the second parameter to the `validation` is the domain class instance being validated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `defineBeans`? Since this is a unit test you have to explicitly define the beans. This how it is normally done in JUnit

```
defineBeans{
    userHelper(UserHelper){bean ->
        //in case you have other beans defined inside helper
        bean.autowire = true 
    }
}
```

You can `defineBeans` in the setup method to make it available for all the test cases.

```
@Before
void setup(){
    defineBeans{
        userHelper(UserHelper){bean ->
            //in case you have other beans defined inside helper
            bean.autowire = true 
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Seems like in case of spock you can directly inject a spring bean inside a Unit Test (test which extends `Specification`)

```
class UserControllerSpecification extends Specification {
    def userHelper //injected here in case of spock

    def "save user" () {
     ................
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm that didn't work. I added the `defineBeans` in the `given` section

Comment: unfortunately, this isn't working for me. I keep getting the same error that validatePassword cant be invoked on null object. I'm running my test cases like this `grails test-app unit:spock` I tried putting it in the functional folder as well but no luck (ran with `grails test-app functional:spock`)

Comment: @Anthony I think you can directly inject the bean in a spock unit test. Have a look at the update and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11953052/2051952) as well.

Comment: Can you have `defineBeans` in [`setup:`](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics#Blocks) instead of `given:`

Comment: @dmahapatro the answer you are referring to is an integration test, not a unit test! That is why they can inject a bean into the test.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the metaClass.

```
def setup(){
    User.metaClass.getUserHelper = {new UserHelper()}
}
```

You could also mock userHelper if that's what you want.

```
def setup(){
    def userHelperMock = Mock(UserHelper)
    userHelperMock.validatePassword(_) >> true
    User.metaClass.getUserHelper = {userHelperMock}
}
```

Make sure you are calling `getUserHelper()` and **not** accessing the private `userHelper` property directly.  It might be a good idea to make that explicit:

```
password nullable: false, blank: false, validator: {pwd, userInstance ->
    return this.getUserHelper().validatePassword(pwd)
}
```

@dmahapatro 's answer to use `defineBeans{...}` is the *best* way, but I think it's not working because of [this grails bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9808)...

The other suggestion to directly inject the bean into the test will only work in an integration test that extends `grails.plugin.spock.IntegrationSpec`.