# Using custom renderer in grails unit testing (and in general) on JSON content types

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-controller

I am trying to get a custom JSON renderer for exceptions working in my REST api.

I was able to get a custom marshaller working that did most of what I needed, but I would like to have control over the context that I don't have access to in the marshaller.  The grails documentation shows how to write a custom renderer, and I have one that I think should work, but I can't use it during unit testing my REST controller.

Grails docs: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/webServices.html#customRenderers

Does anyone know how I would initialize this renderer to be used in my controller actions during unit testing?

The above documentation only says how to set it up in the resources.groovy file.

When I was using the marshaller, I was able to do:

```
def setup(){
    //Set up the custom JSON marshallers
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(new CusomMarshaller(), 1)
}
```

But I don't see an equivalent method for Renderers.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

Further details:

Here is my renderer:

```
class JSONExceptionRenderer extends AbstractRenderer<Exception>{

JSONExceptionRenderer(){
    super(Exception, [MimeType.JSON, MimeType.HAL_JSON, MimeType.TEXT_JSON] as MimeType[])
}

@Override
void render(Exception object, RenderContext context) {
    log.warn("RENDERING")
    Exception exception = (Exception) object

    //Default to internal error
    Integer code = 500

    //If it is a defined exception with a more appropriate error code, then set it
    if(exception instanceof RestException){
        code = (Integer) ((RestException) exception).getCode()
    }else if(exception instanceof MissingResourceException){
        code = 404
    }
    context.status = HttpStatus.valueOf(code)

    //Write the JSON
    Writer writer = context.getWriter()
    Map content = ["code":code, "status":"error", "message":exception.message]
    JsonBuilder builder = new JsonBuilder(content)
    builder.writeTo(writer)

}
}
```

And this is the way I am trying to get it to work:

```
try{
  log.info "Throwing exception"
  throw new NullPointerException("Test Exception")
}catch(Exception ex){
  render ex as JSON
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use spock or basic junit for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spock, you can inject the bean directly in `Specification`.

```
@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerSpec extends spock.lang.Specification {
     def myCustomRenderer //bean name used in resources.groovy

     //continue with tests
}
```

If you are using junit tests, then you can use [defineBeans](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.1/guide/testing.html) as:

```
@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerTests {
    void setup() {
         defineBeans {
            myCustomRenderer(com.example.MyCustomRenderer)
         }
    }

    //continue with tests
}
```

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17173016/2051952) as well for use of defineBeans.

I believe this is what you just need to do to test the behavior of the renderer.

Comment: That was what I was looking for, but it still doesn't seem to use the renderer that I made and setup.  I have attached to the original post my specific renderer and how I am calling it.

Comment: Maybe that means this question was "answered" ;-)

Comment: Have you registered the renderer as a bean in `resources.groovy`?

Comment: Yea, and it doesn't get called from there either.  Do you know what "triggers" a particular renderer to get called?

Comment: I don't see a `contentType` being set to the `RenderContext` inside `render()` in the custom renderer. Shouldn't there be `context.contentType = MimeType.JSON.name`. I may be incorrect, I have not fully tested the renderer myself.

Comment: That is probably true, and thank you for pointing it out, but I am not even "entering" the render method.  I thought the renderer would be triggered by the MIME type used in the constructor, so in my case any JSON type.  or if I did ```render CLASS as JSON``` it would find any renderer that was set up with CLASS with TYPE of JSON.

Comment: Have you also tried `respond ex` instead of `render ex as JSON`. I am unable to test this feature right now. Will give it a shot when feasible.

Comment: Ha!  Just saw this, and I came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging around in the source. I thought I would post this here for others.

The reason my custom renderer didn't work was you have to use the "respond" method on the controller:

```
respond object
```

That will check the class ControllersRestApi with a very large respond method to find your renderer in the rendererRegistry and use it.  This is different than the object marshallers which use the `render as` notation.

In addition you need to also flush the writer, which wasn't in the orgininal documentaiton:

```
builder.writeTo(writer)
writer.flush()
```