# Spock spring module results in NoSuchMethodError when running the test

Tags: java, spring, maven, spock

I am using the following spock dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

I wrote this test

```
class JsonIncludeResolverTest extends Specification {
    JsonIncludeResolver uut;
    def "test"(){
       expect:
       true
    }
}
```

> the test succeeds

Now I want to use Spring to inject `JsonIncludeResolver`within the specification.
`JsonIncludeResolver` is annotated with `@Component` and is injected successfully when running the application. Both tests and component are placed in the same maven module.

I read about `spring-spock` here: [How to inject spring beans into spock test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811345/how-to-inject-spring-beans-into-spock-test#)

Therefore I added this dependency version

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
      <version>1.1-groovy-2.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

after adding this dependency running the s

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.isAnnotationPresentRecursive(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at org.spockframework.spring.SpringExtension.isSpringSpec(SpringExtension.java:83)
at org.spockframework.spring.SpringExtension.visitSpec(SpringExtension.java:59)
at org.spockframework.runtime.ExtensionRunner.runGlobalExtensions(ExtensionRunner.java:46)
at org.spockframework.runtime.ExtensionRunner.run(ExtensionRunner.java:40)
at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.runExtensionsIfNecessary(Sputnik.java:88)
at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.getDescription(Sputnik.java:55)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.getDescription(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I then tried to use the proper annotations

```
@ContextConfiguration
class JsonIncludeResolverTest extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    JsonIncludeResolver uut;
    def "test"(){
       expect:
       uut != null
    }
}
```

Still the result is the above exception.

The groovy test is under `/src/test/groovy` which is a working as you could see in the first successful run of the test.

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` indicates incompatible jar versions

Comment: would you recommend me to use older versions of `spring-spock` ?

Comment: I recommend to use compatible Versions of spring and spock-spring

Comment: how to figure out this compability?

Comment: look into maven repo for the spock-Version and you will see the compatibility to spring https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-spring/1.1-groovy-2.4

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading Spock to 1.1 as follows:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-groovy-2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

`org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.isAnnotationPresentRecursive()` has been introduced since version 1.1 by [this commit](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/commit/a7fffb130f4d39b045905b6ea70aaa2e8d657063#diff-581ee192a9b9299778b1a2e1ffef3979).